# I don't understand the python callback function

Tags: python, callback

This is my python callback function:

```
from time import sleep

def callback(sum):
    sleep(5)
    print("Sum = {}".format(sum))

def main(a, b, callback = None):
    print("adding {} + {}".format(a, b))
    if callback:
        callback(a+b)
    print('leaving u')

main(1, 2, callback)
```

This is the output:

```
adding 1 + 2
Sum = 3
leaving u
```

But I expected it to be:

```
adding 1 + 2
leaving u
Sum = 3
```

I thought a callback function was suppose to be used in the case where there is a function that will take a lot of time. Therefore it made sense to me that it would run in the background and the next line in the main function would continue executing.

Comment: You are not using threads or an event loop with asynchronous calls, so this will just step through each line of code in order. Calling a function `callback` doesn't change the calling semantics. You may want to look into how `asyncio` works, e.g. `asyncio.sleep()` would allow other processing to continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sleep` is synchronous (meaning, until its done, nothing else is being executed). For asynchronous tasks, consider using threading:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def callback (sum):
    print("Sum = {}".format(sum))

def main (a, b, callback = None):
    print("adding {} + {}".format(a, b))
    if callback:
        calling = ThreadPool(processes=1)
        registered_async = calling.apply_async(callback, args=(a+b,))
    print('leaving u')
    while not registered_async.ready(): pass

main(1, 2, callback=callback)
```

Comment: Wouldn't `if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main(1, 2, callback=callback)
` make your answer better (i.e., into a [mcve]).

Comment: @Uriel Thanks for the explanation, but when I ran the code the sum never is printed. Using python 2.7

Comment: @boardrider a canonical answer for this would be an overkill and will divert from course. also, this suggestion goes for asking, not answering

Comment: The `main(1, 2, callback=callback)` does the job.